# Bind dropdown with the values from 2 cells in another worksheet

Tags: macros, microsoft-excel-2016, dropdownlist

I have dropdown contorl in sheet1. Then in sheet2 the values like, 'D2' value 2010, 'D3' value 2020. So now, I want to populate this dropdownlist with values 2010,2011,2012,,,,2019,2020(on workbook open event). How can i achieve this in VB Macro..
Can anyone help me to solve this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What sort of 'dropdown' control are you talking about? Is it a data validation list, a forms combo-box, an ActiveX combobox, or something else?

Comment: Its ActiveX combobox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will populate the ActiveX ComboBox with all values between Sheet2!D2 and Sheet2!D3:

```
Sub PopulateComboBox()
    Dim l As Long
    Dim cb As ComboBox

    On Error GoTo Terminate

    Set cb = Sheet1.ComboBox1

    cb.Clear

    With Sheet2
        For l = .Range("D2").Value To .Range("D3").Value
            cb.AddItem l
        Next l
    End With

Terminate:
    If Err Then
        Debug.Print "Error", Err.Number, Err.Description
        Err.Clear
    End If
End Sub
```

To run when the workbook opens, then put this in the workbook module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Call PopulateComboBox
End Sub
```

You may also want to put this in the Sheet2 worksheet module, so that the ComboBox values are updated if the values in D2 or D3 change:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D2:D3")) Is Nothing Then Call PopulateComboBox
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi olly thak for your response. Its working for me while change to sheet3 and come to sheet2, yet not loaded properly when open the workbook. I used 'With Worksheets("MonthYearConfig")' in workbook_open event

Comment: Just call the subroutine from the workbook_open event.